# How to run a async database task in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

I want to start a long-running database operation in a new thread. So the persistence context must be available but there is no return value (or the return value is not needed). Usually i do:

```java
@Inject
MyRepository panachRepo;

new Thread(() -> {
    panachRepo.cleanupDatabase();
});
```

how do i achieve this in quarkus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Inject
ManagedExecutor managedExecutor;
```

Then you can submit a task to it.

```
managedExecutor.execute(() -> methodToExecute());
```